# Facebook api graph access token

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

there is any way to get the access token automatically with python using login informations ?

Something like this :

> import requests
>
> r=requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=get_token&
>   client_id=idclient_secret=password&privilege=')
>
> print r.text

Comment: That is of course not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't get users access token without users interaction.

You can get app token though like this:

```
facebook.get_app_access_token(APP_ID, APP_SECRET)
```

To get APP_ID and APP_SECRET you need to create new app here: https://developers.facebook.com/ Note that you will get much less meta data using app's token than using user's token.

I was writing script collecting data from facebook lately and I had same problem. I just switched to app token since my script runs every hour as cron job so it was impossible to deliver new token every time manually.

Comment: hi lenartowski , yeap i'm doing the exact thing you're doing cron job , the probleme you can't comment on posts with access token generated from the apps , i can't get anything with API v2.4 , or there is any changes in the paths or something ?

cause everything works great with the other version except 2.4

Comment: and with the access token generated from the app you can only use v2.4.

Comment: Oh I see. I only needed to collect data to do some statistics so I don't know about posting but it makes sense if you can't post with app token.

Comment: But now I'm thinking that you could scrape developers site https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to get value of user's token. I don't know what fb policy says about it since it's kind of workaround so personally I don't recomend it

Comment: tried to do so , but i didn't figure out how to login in fb with python , thanks for the help man